# How to convert a variable's datatype of a POJO from main method? any API

Tags: java, pojo

Do we have any API by which we can change the data type of a variable of a POJO from main method?

any API available for that? If so, Please provide me how to implement it.

Thank you so much,

Harish Raj.

Answer (score 1):

Literally POJO: Plain Old Java Object, so it exposes it's datas via methods, if the POJO doesn't provide method to accesso its data in your desired format/type, you should access it via its methods and then perform conversion.

Now, let's dig a bit, you've got a java main, and a POJO, how's the POJO related to your main ? Is it a class referenced directly or you access it in some other ways ?

Please clarify your scenario.

Regards

```
public String convertToString(XMLGregorianCalendar cal)
{
  return "" + cal.getYear() + "/" + cal.getMonth() + "/" + cal.getDay();
}
```

of course you may need to add some checks on nulls or values (written out of the box without thinkin much, but shall do the trick)

Comment: Ok, Mike. I have JAXB 2.0 generated POJOs in which I have variables of the XMLGregorianCalendar datatype and in my main class, I developed as like I can give xml format and get json format using google-gson API. But this API supports only string and none other datatype. certainly I dont want to change my POJO's XMLGregorianCalendar datatype and use some other APIs, as the instructions given to me. I am stuck here, Mike. Please help me with your Ideas :(

Comment: can't you just extend your pojo, add a convenience method and use the derived class in your main ?

Comment: I gave you a simple senario. what if I had 10 POJOs?

Comment: well inherit from 10 classes or write a single custom class accessing via BeanUtils the XMLGregorian calendar and converting it to GregorianCalendar. If the POJOs have a common base class you can extend that one, writing your function just once and then make the POJOs inherit from your class.

Comment: I want XMLGregorianCalendar datatype to be String. my API will only support String. It would be great help if you could give me example of a sample program converting XMLGregorianCalendar datatype to String.

Comment: so basically you need to convert an XMLGregorianCalendar to a string (I don't know in what kind of format Google's APIs expect string). I guess a simple toString() won't work. You can use XMLGregorianCalendar  methods (getDay(), getMonth(), getYear()) to compose the desired string. http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5,0/docs/api/javax/xml/datatype/XMLGregorianCalendar.html for a summary of XMLGregorianCalendar methods.

Answer (score 0):

How is it possible to change the data type? You can only type cast the data but cannot convert the data type. What do you really mean by changing the datatype of a variable of POJO.